# How to pass variables from 1 function to another

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to pass variable from one function in codeigniter to another they are sharing the same class. they are part of form.

```
class C_Reservation extends CI_Controller {

 private $params = array();
 private $post;
 public function index()
     {
          $this->params['post'] = array(
                'name' => '',
                'last_name'=>''
          );

          $this->load->view('common/default_header',$this->params);
          $this->load->view('reservation/index',$this->params);
          $this->load->view('common/default_footer');

     }

        public function add(){
            $error =false;
            $error_list =array();

            session_start();
            $this->load->library('InputProcess');
            $this->load->library('session');

            if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')!="POST"){
                show_404("Formularz dodawania obiektu - brak danych POST");
            }

            //filtrowanie danych

            $this->post=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'last_name'=>$this->input->post('last_name')
            );
            echo $this->post['name']; // this place is showing name from form
            $this->load->view('common/default_header',$this->params);
            $this->load->view('reservation/complete',$this->params);
            $this->load->view('common/default_footer');

        }

     public function export_pdf(){
         session_start();

         $html=$this->load->view('pdf/index', $this->post,false);
         $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $pdf->Output();
     }
}
```

add function is unfinished it just need to "save" variable that i can acces it from function export_pdf 
anyone ?

Comment: If your 2 functions are into the same class, but 2 different object (of this class) need to use the same value, use a `static` variable. so every object of this class will see the same value...

Comment: use $thtis->export_pdf() and add a return "variable to be saved" in export pdf .

Comment: What variable do you want in both functions? Which is the first function, and which is the second? Please explain the process of how your application works.

Comment: add function take arguments from form that is in views  what i want is to pass that variables (from form) e.g name, last_name to export_pdf function where i can make confirmation in pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. The reason is confusing is because you are not explaining the process of how the application flows. Taking in consideration all the comments, I believe the flow is like this:

When a user adds a reservation to the system:

- a POST request is sent to the `add()` function
- the function makes sure it is a POST request
- the function sets the POST values to class variable ($this->post)
- the function checks if the user wants a PDF output
- If yes, then should run the `export_pdf()` to create a pdf
- If no, then the completed html should be returned

If the above is your desired flow, then problem lies in your `add()` and `export_pdf()` functions. The function needs to make sure the `export_pdf()` is called, and `export_pdf()` needs to return the data, but currently nothing is running that function.

I would rewrite both functions like this:

```
public function add(){
    $error = false;
    $error_list = array();

    session_start();
    $this->load->library('InputProcess');
    $this->load->library('session');

    if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')!="POST"){
        show_404("Formularz dodawania obiektu - brak danych POST");
    }

    //filtrowanie danych

    $this->post = $this->input->post();
    if ($this->post['user_needs_pdf'] == TRUE) {
        $this->export_pdf();
    } else {
        $this->load->view('common/default_header',$this->params);
        $this->load->view('reservation/complete',$this->params);
        $this->load->view('common/default_footer');
    }
}

public function export_pdf(){
    $html = $this->load->view('pdf/index', $this->post, false);
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output();
 }
```

Comment: ok it`s working but there is another problem how to pass whole html variable to function that is making pdf file

Comment: which function is in charge of making the pdf file? and how?

Comment: sory … i didnt copy it .. ehh i made some edit in my post  public function output($file){

$html = "wp .pl";
$this->load->library('m_pdf');
$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output();

}

Comment: ok I updated my answer. Try it . You will need to make sure that you send a POST request with an extra boolean value with user input either saying true or false, depending if they want a PDF.

Comment: thats one of way but i wanted that user can choose if he want pdf after complete

Comment: how? would it be using a "View as PDF" button?, perhaps provide the HTML of your complete.php view

Answer (score 0):

If your are not calling both function at the same time, you have to store value in cookie/session, then only one can get values from one method to another. Remember HTTP is stateless state.

other wise simple $this->export_pdf($f_name, $l_name);
retrieve it with function export_pdf($f_name, $l_name){....}
or in your case $this->export_pdf(); and in function export_pdf(){$f_name=$this->post['f_name']; $l_name=$this->post['l_name'];}

Comment: its not exacly what i wanted. it loads function export_pdf and i dont see the result of add function
it should be optional for user to get pdf ;p

Comment: Sorry your question is confusing. I am not getting the flow. i have done HTML to PDF converter in some project. The pdf would be downloaded when user used to click button.